# I wired a scammer some money, what now?

Tags: scams, online-banking, wire-transfer

I mistakenly made a wire transfer (through swift) to an online scammer. I then asked my bank to issue a recall, which didn't work. Then I let them issue a fraudulent recall, now the receiver says the fund is put on hold. What does that mean? What now?

Comment: Did you tell the recipient you were trying to reverse the transfer?  If you told him, he might lie and say the funds were taken back, because if you think your recall worked, you'll stop trying.

Comment: Yes, I told them I recalled. Now what should I do?

Comment: Trust your bank for status information.  Don't trust anything the scammer says.

Comment: If the funds is put on hold, what should I do? Is there anyway to reverse it back?

Comment: How much was the wire, and what are the source and destination countries?

Answer (score 11):

> **the receiver says the fund is put on hold. What does that means?**

It means you shouldn't trust people who have scammed you.

> **What now?**

Stop communicating with the scammer.

Work with your bank and your local police

Comment: It is an international transfer, local police don't care about my case. :(

Comment: Sorry to hear that - write off the money and get on with your life.